# Serve resource files bypassing a framework using .htaccess directives

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http

I'm using the Kohana framework. It has the following configuration of `.htaccess` file:

```
# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php [PT]
```

I'm particulary interested in the second part `Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly`. Can someone please elaborate in details on how it's configured?

Answer (score 0):

It is due to 2 condition lines using `RewriteCond` directive that acts like `if condition`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Means if request is NOT for a valid file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Means if request is NOT for a valid directory

Both combined with `RewriteRule` below mean that if request is not a valid file or directory then forward every request to `index.php`